# FastAPI many to many Response Schema and Relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am new to FastAPI and SQL-Alchemy, I am having trouble creating a schema and relationship of the many-to-many table (association table).

Here is an example, a student can enroll in multiple courses and a single course can have multiple students thus making many-to-many relationship.

## Database Models

```
class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = "student"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)


class Course(Base):
    __tablename__ = "course"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)


class StudentCourse(Base):
    __tablename__ = "student_course"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    student_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("student.id"), nullable=False)
    course_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("course.id"), nullable=False)
```

What relation do I need to define and how to design a schema from which I can get the following responses:

#### Response 1

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Student A",
    "courses": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Course A"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Course B"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Student B",
    "courses": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Course A"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Course C"
      }
    ]
  },
  {...}
]
```

#### Response 2

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Course A",
    "students": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Student A"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Student B"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Course B",
    "students": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Student A"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Course C",
    "students": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Student B"
      },
    ]
  },
  {...}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it is simpler and preferable to use an association table instead of an association object for this many-to-many relationship, since you don't need extra fields.
So, according to the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many), your database models should be:

```py
student_course = Table("student_course", Base.metadata,
                       Column("student_id", ForeignKey("student.id"), primary_key=True),
                       Column("course_id", ForeignKey("course.id"), primary_key=True))

class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = "student"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    courses = relationship("Course",
                           secondary=student_course,
                           back_populates="students")


class Course(Base):
    __tablename__ = "course"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    students = relationship("Student",
                            secondary=student_course,
                            back_populates="courses")
```

and your pydantic models (schemas):

```py
class Student(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class Course(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class StudentOut(Student):
    courses: List[Course]


class CourseOut(Course):
    students: List[Student]
```

where `StudentOut` and `CourseOut` are your response models

Comment: I'll check and get back to you soon :)